# Rewriting a SQL without repeating a parameter

Tags: sql

I have written the below query but  I now I would like to refine the code and the ultimate requirement is not to repeat any parameters twice. Is there a way to rewrite this sql query without repeating Flag1 and Flag2 parameters without affecting the logic?

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN  @PARAM1 = 'REV' THEN SUM(NET_INVOICE_REVENUE) ELSE SUM(QUANTITY) END VAL 
FROM 
 PA_TRANS TR 
JOIN 
 PA_SOLD_TO CUST 
ON 
 TR.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER = CUST.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER 
WHERE  
 AGREEMENT_NBR = @AGREEMENT_CSV 
AND 
 PART_NUMBER = @PART_NUMBER 
AND 
 CUST.WW_CORP = CASE WHEN (@FLAG1 = 'N' AND @FLAG2 ='N') THEN @WW_CORP ELSE CUST.WW_CORP END 
AND 
 CUST.WW_AFFLIATE = CASE WHEN (@FLAG1 = 'N' AND @FLAG2 ='Y') THEN @WW_AFFLIATE ELSE       CUST.WW_AFFLIATE END 
AND  
   ( DAY >= @A_START_DATE AND  DAY < @A_END_DATE)
```

Thanks.
Mayurika

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You could use FLAG1 and FLAG2 in a subquery....  but out of curiosity, what's the issue with having them twice?

Comment: There are ways to do it, but they're not really worth doing in this example.   What is the reason you don't want to repeat the parameters?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Thanks All. I am using the query inside a xml file and this file identifies ? mark symbol as the parameters. there is no way that I can map the passed on parameters in this file with names. Each ? mark is mapped sequentially in the script by default with what parameters I am passing .

Comment: Cont..... Each ? mark is mapped sequentially in the script by default. EX- CUSTOM_SQL("GET_SUM",PAram1,Param2,Param3)  n lets say I have SQL as SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM TRANS WHERE CUST = ? and CITY = ?and SUBS = ? . SO by default 1st ? = Param1 2nd ? = Param2 and so on.. NOw if I want to use param2 twice in my query then I need to send it twice which is not elegant. And so wanted to solve it at SQL level itself.          Ma

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to mention parameters once, you can use a CTE or subquery.  Here is the subquery form:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p_PARAM1 = 'REV' THEN SUM(NET_INVOICE_REVENUE) ELSE SUM(QUANTITY)
        END) as VAL 
FROM (select @PARAM1 as p_param1, @AGREEMENT_CSV as p_AGREEMENT_CSV,
             @PART_NUMBER as p_PART_NUMBER, @FLAG1 as p_FLAG1, @FLAG2 as p_FLAG2,
             @A_START_DATE as p_A_START_DATE, @A_END_DATE as p_A_END_DATE
     ) params CROSS JOIN
     PA_TRANS TR JOIN
     PA_SOLD_TO CUST 
     ON  TR.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER = CUST.SOLD_TO_CUSTOMER 
WHERE AGREEMENT_NBR = p_AGREEMENT_CSV AND 
      PART_NUMBER = p_PART_NUMBER AND 
      CUST.WW_CORP = CASE WHEN (p_FLAG1 = 'N' AND p_FLAG2 ='N') THEN @WW_CORP ELSE CUST.WW_CORP END AND 
      CUST.WW_AFFLIATE = CASE WHEN (p_FLAG1 = 'N' AND p_FLAG2 ='Y') THEN @WW_AFFLIATE ELSE       CUST.WW_AFFLIATE END AND  
      ( DAY >= p_A_START_DATE AND  DAY < p_A_END_DATE);
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It fixed my problem.